Can't make opacity expression work for a altair chart
I want to plot an altair chart in streamlit. So I wrote a code based on documentation Interactive Section.
I'm trying to plot a bar char that has a search input which makes all the bars that doesn't contain the input string opaque.
The code is as follows:
    data = pd.DataFrame({'Profissional':data.index, 'Quantidade': data.values})

    search_input = alt.param(
        value='',
        bind=alt.binding(
            input='search',
            placeholder="Profissional",
            name='Pesquisar ',
        )
    )
    st.write(alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
        x=alt.X('Profissional', sort=None),
        y='Quantidade',
        opacity=alt.condition(
            alt.expr.test(alt.expr.regexp(search_input, 'i'), alt.datum.Profissional),
            # f"test(regexp({search_input.name}, 'i'), datum.Profissional)",  # Equivalent js alternative
            alt.value(1),
            alt.value(0.05)
            )
        ).properties(
            width=700,
        ).add_params(
            search_input
        )
    )

But I'm getting the error:
enter image description here
I think it doesn't recognize alt.datum.Profissional. I also don't know if  I'm using it correctly since I didn't find anything too specific in the documentation.

Usually that error comes up if you are trying to reference a param that has not been added to a chart. Since that number is so high 379, maybe you can restart and run from scratch to make sure you don't have a previously defined variable anywhere? I would also try just included the minimal example from the docs in a streamlit app without anything else.
